# Function that doubles value by various rates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a line chart like the New York Times [Coronavirus Deaths by U.S. State and Country Over Time: Daily Tracker](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/03/21/upshot/coronavirus-deaths-by-country.html?smtyp=cur&smid=fb-nytupshot).

NYT has some clever lines in the chart showing the doubling rate, every day, every 2 days, every 3 days, every week, and so on.
I'm wondering how to write a function that returns an array of values that represent these lines given a start value of 10 and a maxX-value of 36 (total number of days as of today).

This is where I'm at right now, I'm afraid it does not calculate the values correctly but it might explain what I want to achieve.

How can I do this in a correct way? My math is too rusty for this.

```js
var maxX = 36;
var start = 10;

function double(factor) {
  var f = start;
  var arr = [f];
  for (var i = 1; i < maxX; i++) {
    f = f + (f / factor)
    arr.push(f)
  }
  return arr
}

var lines = [1, 2, 3, 7, 30].map(f => {
  return {
    days: f,
    arr: double(f)
  }
})
console.log(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to figure out what to multiply each daily value by, given a doubling rate. For example, with a doubling rate of every 2 days, you'd want each day count to be multiplied by 1.412 (square root of 2); after 1 day, it'd be 1.412x, after 2 days, it'd be 2x, after 4 days, it'd be 4x, etc.

For the general solution, the equation to solve is:

```
orig * (dayFactor ** daysToDouble) = 2 * orig
```

where `orig` is the original number of infections (here, 10), and `dayFactor` is the value you want to solve for, since that's the number the infections should be multiplied each day.

```
orig * (dayFactor ** daysToDouble) = 2 * orig
(dayFactor ** daysToDouble) = 2
dayFactor = 2 ** (1 / daysToDouble)
```

In the function, identify the `dayFactor` given the doubling rate, then multiply the count by that each day:

```js
var maxX = 36;
var start = 10;

function double (daysToDouble) {
  const dayFactor = 2 ** (1 / daysToDouble);
  let currentInfected = start;
  const arr = [currentInfected];
  for (var i = 1; i < maxX; i++){
    currentInfected *= dayFactor;
    arr.push(currentInfected);
  }
  return arr;
}

var lines = [1,2,3,7,30].map(f => {
  return {days: f, arr: double(f)}
});

console.log(lines[2]); // double every 3rd day
```